# Dynamically add LinearLayout into LinearLayout

Tags: android, onclick, android-linearlayout, android-view

I have a issue trying to dynamically add some linear layout into a linearlayout container after user have clicked on a button.

```
private void AddView() {
    MyView myView1 = new MyView("Name");
    this.mainLinearLayout.addView(myView1);
}
```

This code works great in activity's onCreate method but not after handling user event.

Do you have any idea why it's not working ? (I mean nothing appears on UI)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AddView(); => works great
}

playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AddView(); => not working 
    }
});
```

Thanks,

Comment: are you sure you onclick is being hit?

Comment: how come the playButton.setOnClickListener is outside the onCreate()?

Comment: @TomerShemesh Yes I have put a breakpoint in and it breaks .. Well I really don't understand why it doesn't work !

Comment: try commenting out the one in on create, maybe it is only working on the first call

Comment: @AlexGoja It's just a sample of the code

Comment: ok, do you invalidate the view so that it is redrawn again? so i guess the mainLinearLayout is the root, try to invalidate it after you added your view. mainLinearLayout.invalidate();

Comment: I have tried but it's still the same .. My container has the right number of children but I can't see all of them ..

Comment: Are previous child `View`s filling the `LinearLayout`, and the ones you're adding just off-screen? Make sure the `LinearLayout`'s `orientation` is what you're expecting, as well. The default is `horizontal`.

Comment: Actually when I call like 5 times my AddView method in onCreate it works as expected .. But when I call 4 times in onCreate and 1 time when I press the button it's not adding anything ..

Comment: It's a bit like you can't expand the size of the layout once it is already defined and my last view is not visible so ..

Comment: Well, we can't tell you exactly what the problem is from just what you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

I think that AddView is wrong.

```
private void addView() {
    LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(
       LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    MyView myView1 = new MyView("Name");
    myView1.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    this.mainLinearLayout.addView(myView1);
}
```

Comment: Well you are not wrong but I set the layoutParams inside MyView class !

Comment: You add the same view right, why not create a list and have a list adapter that takes as item your MyView class which I assume is extending View, and when you want to add a new one you just tell the adapter to increase by 1 the size of its items and then you notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Yes it could work to use a list and an adapter.. I'm going to try it to see if it works better !